# Meaning of を作画 at the end of sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-を

In a manual about welding I encountered the following sentences:

> (3)FSWを行う継手について，表面(A)に垂直な直線(B)**を作画**
>
> (4)表面(A)から距離440mm位置の直線(B)上の点(C)**を作画**

I am not sure if を作画 means "Drawing of the straight line..." or if it means "Draw the straight line". Does it refer to the drawings on the right or is it telling to draw and する has just been omitted? Since there is を, I think it is telling to perform the action of drawing. To mean "Drawing of..." there should be **の**作画, right?

Since I also encountered を算出, を決定 and similar expressions, could you confirm that in instruction manuals these kind of expressions placed at the end of sentences are always telling to perform the action indicated by the noun with the omission of する? Or can they be plain nouns meaning "calculation of..., determination of..., drawing of..."? Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since this 作画 is used with ～を, it's a verb. Omission of する happens all the time in a manual like this.